# Exception Handling: Meaning and Semantics

Tags: exception

exception handling: what do they actually do.

consider the scenario that I am reading a file for input and I want to put try/catch the file opening and reading code within a try/catch clause.
What happens if there is error in reading the file(file doesnt exists etc). The code goes to the catch block, but what should I put in there.

What is the use of catch block, does the catch block suspends the normal running of the program and the program exists after the catch block?

Thanks in advance for clearing these doubts!!!

Comment: dont they mean the same in most languages? Anyways in Java, C++ and Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a specific language, I'm just going to answer as a general concept.

When an exception is hit, the code will jump to the catch block, skipping over all code between the exception and the catch block.

There is no general answer to what you should put in the catch.  It depends entirely on your specific case.  You will often want to log the error somewhere and then take some appropriate action.  What an "appropriate action" is can vary greatly.  If the code which is failing is initiated by a user, you would want to return some error message to the user.  If it is in some sort of nightly job you may want to send an email alerting someone of the problem, etc.

Comment: Also i have seen something like OutofBounds Exception. Does this exception mean that we are trying to access wrong index of an array. Does not that mean that there is someting wrong with the code as if written properly there should not be an outofbounds exception thrown

Comment: Again, unsure of which language we are discussing here, but yes, OutOfBounds means you are trying to access an item in an array that is out of the bounds of the array.  Say your array has 3 elements and you try to access the 5th, that will throw this exception.  In general this is caused by badly written code.

Comment: OK let zoom down to C++ with a specific example given below (this example is taken from an exception handling tutorial)

try {
  // code here
}
catch (int param) { cout << "int exception"; }
catch (char param) { cout << "char exception"; }
catch (...) { cout << "default exception"; }

Here all I see in the catch block in printing to stdout that an error occurred. Is that what we are supposed to do in exception handling (catch an error and print error msg, along with freeing any acquired resources )